# Using three dots/ellipsis (...) for column names with both dplyr and merge()

Tags: r

I have a function where I first use `group_by()` on a number of column names passed to the function, followed by a merge on these same column names.

I can do the `group_by()` using `vars <- enquos(…)` followed by `group_by(!!!vars)`.  This requires that the column names passed to the function are not in quote marks, or else the `group_by()` creates new column names with the quotes included.

I can do a merge by using `vars <- list(…)` followed by `merge(x, y, by = paste(vars))`.  However this requires that the column names **are** in quotes, else `list(…)` generates:

> error (object 'x' not found).

How can I handle both of these cases at the same time?

Example:

```
example <- function(...) {
  vars1 <- enquos(...) #doesn't work unless (...) isn't in quotes
  #vars2 <- list(...) #doesn't work unless (...) is in quotes

  df1 <- mtcars %>%
    group_by(!!!vars1) %>%
    summarise(Mean = mean(mpg))

  df2 <- mtcars %>%
    group_by(!!!vars1) %>%
    summarise(Median = median(hp))

  merged <- merge(df1, df2, by = "cyl") #for functioning example only, want by to be (...)
  #merged <- merge(df1, df2, by = paste(vars2)) #doesn't work unless (...) is in quotes
  return(merged)
}

out <- example(cyl)
```

Comment: It's hard to debug code without seeing it. Can you add a concrete example of the function you're working on?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide some code. You may want to check: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/ for simpler `{{` (curly curly) approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version which uses quoted variables as input :

```
example <- function(...) {
  vars1 <- syms(...) 
  vars2 <- list(...)
  df1 <- mtcars %>%
         group_by(!!!vars1) %>%
         summarise(Mean = mean(mpg))

  df2 <- mtcars %>%
          group_by(!!!vars1) %>%
          summarise(Median = median(hp))

 merged <- merge(df1, df2, by = vars2[[1]])
 return(merged)

}

example("cyl")
#  cyl  Mean Median
#1   4 26.66   91.0
#2   6 19.74  110.0
#3   8 15.10  192.5

example(c("cyl", "am"))
#  cyl am  Mean Median
#1   4  0 22.90   95.0
#2   4  1 28.07   78.5
#3   6  0 19.12  116.5
#4   6  1 20.57  110.0
#5   8  0 15.05  180.0
#6   8  1 15.40  299.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this operation without passing strings to the function, it just requires a little `rlang` trickery:

```
example <- function(...) {

  df1 <- mtcars %>%
    group_by(...) %>%
    summarise(Mean = mean(mpg))

  df2 <- mtcars %>%
    group_by(...) %>%
    summarise(Median = median(hp))

  merged <- merge(df1, df2, by = sapply(enquos(...), quo_name)) 
  return(merged)
}

example(carb)

#    carb    Mean Median
# 1    1 25.34286     93
# 2    2 22.40000    111
# 3    3 16.30000    180

example(cyl, carb)

#   cyl carb  Mean Median
# 1   4    1 27.58   66.0
# 2   4    2 25.90   93.0
# 3   6    1 19.75  107.5
```