# How can I dynamically group_by a dataframes variables in a function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want a function where i can enter different numbers of column names and have them grouped. The first piece of code here works:

```
df <- data.frame(col_a = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T),
                      col_b = sample(letters, 100, replace = T),
                      col_c = sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = T))


my_fun = function(df, ...) {
  
  df %>% group_by_(...) %>% summarise(n = n())
}

my_fun(df , 'col_a')
my_fun(df , 'col_a', 'col_b')
my_fun(df , 'col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c')
```

What I now want is to apply the complete function, so all possible values in each grouped variable are present. I've manually typed *col_a* and *col_b* into the `complete()` function below. I'd want to pass the possible values as a function argument though, as I'm not always going to be grouping by *col_a* & *col_b*.

```
my_fun = function(df, ...) {
  
  df %>% group_by_(...) %>% summarise(count = n()) %>%
ungroup() %>%
complete(col_a = 1:10, col_b = letters, fill = list(count = 0))

}

my_fun(df , 'col_a', 'col_b')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using three dots/ellipsis (...) for column names with both dplyr and merge()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58926898/using-three-dots-ellipsis-for-column-names-with-both-dplyr-and-merge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the data as named list. `group_by` + `summarise` `n()` can be replaced with `count`.

```
library(tidyverse)

my_fun = function(df, ...) {
  args <- list(...)
  df %>% 
    count(across(all_of(names(args))), name = 'count') %>%
    complete(!!!args, fill = list(count = 0))
}
```

This can be ran as -

```
my_fun(df , 'col_a' = 1:12)

#   col_a count
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1     1     9
# 2     2    15
# 3     3     4
# 4     4    11
# 5     5     7
# 6     6    12
# 7     7    12
# 8     8    10
# 9     9     5
#10    10    15
#11    11     0
#12    12     0


my_fun(df , 'col_a' = 1:10, 'col_b' = letters)

#  col_a col_b count
#   <int> <chr> <dbl>
# 1     1 a         1
# 2     1 b         0
# 3     1 c         0
# 4     1 d         0
# 5     1 e         0
# 6     1 f         1
# 7     1 g         0
# 8     1 h         0
# 9     1 i         0
#10     1 j         0
# … with 250 more rows
```